# How can I suppress the assignment of one or more fields in a Ruby-On-Rails mass-assignment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a bit confused about this mass assignment issue. Here's my question

Say I have a user model with the following attributes:
name
login
password
email

During an edit, the update method is triggered:

```
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if @user.update_attributes(params[:user]) 
   ....
end
```

In my head it makes sense to protect most, if not all, of these attributes as i wouldn't want the password/email/login to be compromised. So I would do this in the model

attr_accessible :name

So every other attribute, asides from name, wouldn't be able to be mass assigned.

If I do this how would the valid edit form work though? Do I need to assign attributes one by one in the update method @user.email = params[:user][:email], etc? Or am I misunderstanding something (probably)?

Thanks!

Edit:

To be more specific:

Usually you see examples with the admin attribute protected. And it makes sense.

But what about the password or email attributes? Those aren't usually protected. Why wouldn't the password be protected or the email? It could mean that potentially somebody could reset the email and do a password reset or reset the password attribute and gain access to the system, no?

Comment: I edited your title; hopefully it captures the question you are asking.  The original title was useless.

Comment: I don't think that's the right title as I'm not asking for that. I think it's a general question of how the protection works. I'm going to edit the question a bit to make it more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watch this railscasts http://railscasts.com/episodes/26-hackers-love-mass-assignment/

You are thinking about mass assignment security the wrong way. attr_accessbile does not make the password value open to the public (you will use filter_parameter to hide that value).

Think of it this way, you have a user form. You want the user to be able to create an account with a password but you do not want them to be able to add themselves as an admin (they could do this through sql injection or manipulating the POST parameters). To protect against this, you would add :name, :password, :email to attr_accessible and leave out the admin field.

Comment: I understand the admin example, I just don't get the password or email part. If I do attr_accessible :email, :login, could an attacker mass assign in the form these two? Would I need to change the update method in any way?

Comment: It is simply stating which attributes a user should be able to create or update through a post request (most likely a form).

Comment: correct. So in the user edit form you can edit the name, email or password. I would like to protect all of those attributes as I think it's a security breach if they aren't. If I do that I wouldn't be able to use update_attributes(params[:user]) though. I would need to do it one by one user.email = params[:user][:email], user.name = params[:user][:name], etc... At least that's what I understand. However, it seems messy to me....

Comment: If you protect all of them then a user would not be able to create an account. A user needs to be able to set a value for their email/username and create a password.

Comment: I understand that, but would it mean that a user could potentially mass assign the password for a given user?

Comment: No, they would not have access to any other users account.

Comment: how? Couldn't an attacker send a post request to update a given user id and along the way reset the password? I'm positive I'm not understanding this correctly but I really want to understand the fundamental issue/fix. Thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13492/discussion-between-user1161661-and-kyle-c)

Comment: A user's username, or user_id should be stored in your session data once they have logged in. Your controller should take care of sending this information to the model from the stored session data, not from the params.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to filter the params in your controller, [as described here](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/3/21/strong-parameters/).

```
class PeopleController < ActionController::Base
  # This will raise an ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributes exception because it's using mass assignment
  # without an explicit permit step.
  def create
    Person.create(params[:person])
  end

  # This will pass with flying colors as long as there's a person key in the parameters, otherwise
  # it'll raise a ActionController::MissingParameter exception, which will get caught by 
  # ActionController::Base and turned into that 400 Bad Request reply.
  def update
    redirect_to current_account.people.find(params[:id]).tap do |person|
      person.update_attributes!(person_params)
    end
  end

  private
    # Using a private method to encapsulate the permissible parameters is just a good pattern
    # since you'll be able to reuse the same permit list between create and update. Also, you
    # can specialize this method with per-user checking of permissible attributes.
    def person_params
      params.required(:person).permit(:name, :age)
    end
end
```